# Jest: How to expect Redux actions to have been dispatched?

Tags: reactjs, redux, jestjs, enzyme

What I'm trying is to make sure that a Redux action, which is passed as a `prop`, to have been dispatched.

I'm trying to spy on the action via `jest`, but keep failing it.

Here is a simplified version of the test...

```
let props;
let wrapped;

describe("Sample", () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    props = {
      setResults: jest.fn()   // This is the action I'm trying to spy on.
    };
    wrapped = mount(
      <Provider store={createStore(reducers, {})}>
        <Sample {...props} />
      </Provider>
    );
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    wrapped.unmount();
  });


  it("can setResults", () => {
    wrapped.find("input").simulate("change", { target: { value: "example" } });
    wrapped.update();
    wrapped.find("button").simulate("click");

    // setResults is supposed to have been called!
    expect(props.setResults).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

Here is how the `setResults` action will be called.

```
const handleEvent = async () => {
    console.log("Before  setResults...");

    setResults(data.results);

    console.log("After  setResults...");

    console.log("What is in setResults?", setResults);
};
```

I put two `console.log()` before and after the action, which confirms that the `handleEvent` function itself is called. Nonetheless, `expect(props.setResults).toHaveBeenCalled()` in the test fails.

When I put `setResults` in the last `console.log()`, I saw that...

```
What is in setResults? results => dispatch((0, _actions.setResults)(results))
```

This made me convinced that **Redux's actions can't be mocked (or, spied on) with jest in this way**.

The action is connected with `react-redux`.

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  setResults: results => dispatch(setResults(results))
});
```

Or, am I missing something in the code above?

Any advice will be appreciated. (The goal is to ensure that an action has been called.)

Answer (score 0):

Unless there's some caveat to wrapping the component in the Provider that I don't know about, this will work:

```
const setResults = jest.fn();
```

in beforeEach callback:

```
beforeEach(() => {
    wrapped = mount(
      <Provider store={createStore(reducers, {})}>
        <Sample setResults={setResults} />
      </Provider>
    );
```

```
it("can setResults", () => {
    wrapped.find("input").simulate("change", { target: { value: "example" } });
    wrapped.find("button").simulate("click");

    expect(setResults).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
```